# Is the set type suitable for an iteration on a loop?

Tags: delphi, enums, set, delphi-6

Have the following enum:

```
TDays = (tdSunday, tdMonday, tdTuesday, tdWednesday, tdThursday, tdFriday, tdSaturday);
```

And the following set of that enum:

```
TChoosenDays = set of TDays;
```

Now, define the following array:

```
var
  ArrayStringDaysAcronym : array [TDays] of String = ('SD', 'MD', 'TU', 'WE', 'TH', 'FR', 'ST');
```

Suppose I have a variable declared as:

```
var
  Foo: TChoosenDays;
begin
  Foo:= [tdSunday, tdMonday, tdTuesday];
```

How can I iterate over all members present in the set?

Note: The following doesn't compile, I know I can use array instead of "set of", is it the only way?

```
function ConcatAcronyms: String;
var
  Item: TDays; 
begin
  Result:= '';
  for Item:= Low(Foo) to High(Foo) do
  begin
    Result:= Result + '; '+ ArrayStringDaysAcronym[Item];
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I am not sure about Delphi 6, but in the modern versions the loop is possible in this way: `var D:TDay; begin for D in Foo do begin SmFnc(D)... end; end;`

Comment: @asd-tm Thanks, but I am stuck on this old version yet

Comment: @asd-tm: the " if Element in []" construct has been around since Pascal was first defined, iirc.  For what it's Wirth.

Comment: @MartynA I was not saying about `if Element in MySet then`. I wrote a looping `for Element in MySet do`

Comment: @asd-tm:  Sure.  I wasn't meaning to contradict ...

Comment: @MartynA I've just found. This looping was introduced in Delphi 2007 for Win32  [http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/34324](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/34324) Unfortunately, it does not suit OP.

Comment: @asd-tm:  Yes I know.  I wasn't saying it was wrong, but as you've seen, the OP is using D6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  Since you're using D6, you could do it this way:

```
function ConcatAcronyms: String;
var
  Item: TDays;
begin
  Result:= '';
  for Item:= Low(TDays) to High(TDays) do
  begin
    if Item in Foo then begin
      if Result <> '' then
        Result := Result + ';'  // assuming you don't want Result to start with  a ';'
      Result:= Result + ArrayStringDaysAcronym[Item];
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Nice, but actually I wish to start with a ';'.

Comment: So am I, although I don't much see the relevance!! ;-) I think it's a mistake to violate DRY here. And I also think that the variant in my edit that got splatted when we crossed is actually cleaner than both of yours.